# Converting string into date does not return the date in specific format

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on Oracle. As you can understand from the title, the problem is in this code:

```
select TO_DATE( '21991231', 'YYYYMMDD' ) from dual;
```

And the result is:

```
31/12/2199
```

I want to achieve this result:

```
21991231
```

Why is Oracle doing this? How can escape this problem?

Comment: You need to use `TO_CHAR (date, 'YYYYMMDD') from dual;`

Comment: @Asjon, that's not what [`to_date`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm) does.

Comment: Why are you converting it at all if it's already in the format you want? You would have to convert your string to a date (which has no intrinsic format!) and then back to a string in the format you want, which seems a bit pointless?

Answer (score 0):

The date doesnt have a format in Oracle. It's your client. 
If you want to modify the default format in the current session, you can use:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='yyyymmdd'
```

If you want to convert the date into a format on adhoc basis, you can use to_char with format string:

```
select to_char(date_col, 'yyyymmdd') from table;
```